# Permissions error while creating plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am creating plugin for the first time. In my main plugin file, I have created a menu with the code:

```
add_menu_page( 
    'custom menu title', 
    'custom menu', 
    'manage_options', 
    'teamstatistics/teamstatistics-admin.php', 
    '', 
    plugins_url( 'teamstatistics/images/icon.png' ), 
    6 
);
```

The issue is that when I go the URL it's working:

```
http://example.com/mywordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=teamstatistics/teamstatistics-admin.php
```

but when I pass a query string like

```
http://example.com/mywordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=teamstatistics/teamstatistics-admin.php?sid=1
```

It's not working. it is giving

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Answer (score 1):

Your Querystring is **invalid**. The QS starts **only** with one `?`. The name-value-pair is `&name=value` and NOT `?name=value`

**INVALID**:

options-general.php **?** page=teamstatistics/teamstatistics-admin.php **?** sid=1

**VALID**;

options-general.php **?** page=teamstatistics/teamstatistics-admin.php **&** sid=1

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're not using [**`add_menu_page`** parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) correctly. Always check the documentation when something is not working as you expect.

```
add_menu_page( 
    $page_title, 
    $menu_title, 
    $capability, 
    $menu_slug, 
    $function, 
    $icon_url, 
    $position 
);
```

Here's a sample code using `$_GET` in the same plugin page:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'menu_so_22635531' );

function menu_so_22635531()
{
    add_menu_page( 
        'custom menu title', 
        'custom menu', 
        'manage_options', 
        'teamstatistics', 
        'page_so_22635531', 
        plugins_url( 'teamstatistics/images/icon.png' ), 
        6 
    );
}

function page_so_22635531()
{
    // Do your include here

    // Demonstrative code
    echo '<h1>Team Statistics</h1>';
    if( isset( $_GET['sid'] ) )
    {
        $sid = $_GET['sid'];
        echo "<h2>SID = $sid</h2>";
    }
    // Generate test link that goes to
    // http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=teamstatistics&sid=RANDOM-NUMBER
    printf(
        '<a href="%s">Go to new sid</a>',
        admin_url( 'admin.php?page=teamstatistics&sid=').rand()
    );

}
```